# Constant Contact php api v2 and OAuth 2.0

Tags: oauth, oauth-2.0, constantcontact

I would like to implement Constant Contact to my Magento extension. If extension is installed in store it should automatically send e-mail to Constant Contact in live (no cron jobs but instantly) when somebody subscribes newsletter.

I never built OAuth 2.0 application. From what I understand OAuth 2.0 requires to redirect user to api url to retrieve token and then redirect back, correct? Does it mean that when in frontend any user subscribes newsletter it will send him to api url and then back? So there is no way to subscribes him without redirect? Or does it mean that the server where website is installed need to retrieve token in background?

Is there any very simple php wrapper for contant contact api v2 that doesn't require autoload and bunch of files? Something like it was for api v1 where there was only 4 files you needed to include.

thank you!

Answer (score 0):

> Is there any very simple php wrapper for contant contact api v2

Yes.

> that doesn't require autoload and bunch of files

No.

I don't know why you need a small library. You can use official library from constantcontact without a problems https://github.com/constantcontact/php-sdk